# Uses of regex in condition form

Tags: angularjs, regex

I have a little problem with my code.
I would like to only show the key stored in my storage which began with a ' [ ".
I don't know if I have to use the Angular - Pattern because i don't really understand how it works.

Here is my code:

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public _storage: Storage){
  this._storage.forEach( (value, key, index) => {
    //console.log("This is the value", value)
    //console.log("from the key", key)
    //console.log("Index is", index)
    this.questionnaires.push(key);
  })
}
```

This code push the save into a List and it show all the save.
I got two kind of saves in my storage: A questionnaire (Like: [Date] Questionnaire n°X) and a data from a stopWatch (Like: XX min, xx sec, XX; ms).

In the storage, all the save are shown, i would like only the Quesitonnaire so the form which began with a [ .

Thanks for your time !

SCREEN OF THE MAIN PROBLEM:

[image: The list into the app]

[image: The content of _storage]

> WORKS FINE WITH:  if (key.length >= 1 && key[0] === '['){code}

Comment: You can't use `forEach` on a key/value storage. Use `Object.keys(this._storage).forEach( (key) => ...)` instead;

Comment: Mmh i don't see really what to do for now, Object.keys is strange for me

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what is actually contained in `_storage`? Is it an array of objects? A single object with properties? If all you want is items that start with `[` a simple `if(stringValue.indexOf('[') === 0)` should suffice, no?

Comment: I give you the screen in the topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current code is working, just check if keys start with `[` before pushing them, like this:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public _storage: Storage){
    this._storage.forEach( (value, key, index) => {
        if (key.length >= 1 && key[0] === '[')
            this.questionnaires.push(key);
    })
}
```